# Implementing the Java Iterator and Iterable Interface over an Object[] array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, iterator, iterable

Here is my internal class that implements Iterator:

```
public class myIterator implements Iterator<Object> {
    private int pos = 0;

    public boolean hasNext(){
        return pos < arrayPal.length;

    }
    public Object next(){
        return arrayPal[pos++];

    }
}
```

In the class that this internal class is within, DynArray, (which is an object that has an internal array called arrayPal of any type of object, as well as a boolean value that says whether or not the array can store null values) I want to use the iterator for my add method

```
public void add( T ele ) {

    int counter =0;
    int tempIndex =0;
    if(ele == null && this.allowed == false){
        throw new NullPointerException("This array does not accept null values!");
    }

    else{
        myIterator iterator = new myIterator();
        Iterator<T> it = this.iterator();


        for(Object o: this.arrayPal){
            System.out.print(it.hasNext());
            if(it.hasNext() == false && (this.arrayPal.length-1) > counter){
                arrayPal[counter+1] = ele;
            }
            else if (it.hasNext() == false && (arrayPal.length-1) == counter){
                //expand the array by quanta
                //add the the first newest index
                Object[] temp = new Object[this.arrayPal.length + quanta];

                for(Object b: this.arrayPal){
                    temp[tempIndex++] = b;
                }
                temp[this.arrayPal.length] = ele;
                this.arrayPal = temp;

            }
        counter++;
        }
}
```

However the .hasNext() keeps returning true even for the last element in my list. Why is this?

Additionally, it will not allow me to do this.arrayPal.iterator() it says:

Cannot invoke iterator() on the array type 
 Object[]

Why not?

Comment: It's not clear how the iterator is supposed to be related to the add method.  Additionally, you cannot add methods in Java to types you do not control, including `Object[]`.  You can only add methods to e.g. classes like `DynArray` that you write.

Comment: You never call `it.next()` - is that intentional?

Comment: when would I call it.next()? does that cause the iterator to take a step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `add` method obtains a new Iterator and calls `it.hasNext()` multiple times. It never calls `it.next()`, so the `Iterator` keeps pointing on the first element of the array and `hasNext()` will never return false (assuming the array is not empty).